# What was her wish in Haruki Murakami's "Birthday Girl"?

Tags: short-stories, japanese-language, haruki-murakami

Haruki Murakami's short story "Birthday Girl", [available to read online](https://harpers.org/archive/2003/07/birthday-girl/), is about a girl working part-time as a waiter who gets to make a special wish on her twentieth birthday. The first-person narrator of the frame story asks her a couple of questions, about whether her wish came true and whether she ever regretted it, but he refrains from asking the obvious question of what it was. But even though this question isn't explicitly answered in the story, there must be hints towards it.

I have a few questions about this story, but I'll start by addressing the elephant in the room head-on. **What was her wish?** Or what evidence do we have to suggest what it was?